# sed: remove digits after word

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a simple `sed` question.

I have data like this:

```
2600,Sale,"Approved 911973",244.72
2601,Sale,"Approved 04735C",490.51
2602,Sale,"Approved 581068",52.82
2603,Sale,"Approved 009275",88.10
```

How do I make it like this:

```
2600,Sale,Approved,244.72
2601,Sale,Approved,490.51
2602,Sale,Approved,52.82
2603,Sale,Approved,88.10
```

Notice the numbers after *approved* are gone as well as the quotes. I can remove quotes with:

```
sed 's/,$//gn' file
```

but I don't know how to remove the spaces and digits.

Thanks!

Comment: restrict this clause only to your quoted column and apply sed 's/[0-9]*//g'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed "s/\"Approved[^,]*/Approved/g"
```

It finds the quoted "Approved" followed by any non-comma character, up until the first comma encountered, and replaces it with Approved (no quotes)

```
2600,Sale,Approved,244.72
2601,Sale,Approved,490.51
2602,Sale,Approved,52.82
2603,Sale,Approved,88.10
```

Comment: Thanks! this works well as I'll also be able to substitute approved for other things in the file. What's the `*` do at the end?

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help! The `*` matches any amount of the previous expression, which was any character that isn't a comma. So its able to match Approved followed by any number of non-comma characters including spaces,digits,and the closing quotation and has the correctness property of being non-greedy so it will match as much as it can and not more - compare that to `Approved.*,` which could match several other fields in this CSV format which is certainly not what you want !

Answer (score 1):

Using extended regex with `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/"([^[:space:]]*)[^"]*"/\1/g' file
```

The above regex targets for any quoted string. If you want to target the string `Approved`, then:

```
sed -r 's/"(Approved)[^"]*"/\1/g' file
```

With basic regex:

```
sed 's/"\(Approved\)[^"]*"/\1/g' file
```

To target any quoted string, change `Approved` to `[^[:space:]]*`

Answer (score 1):

One way using awk(only if the other columns does not contain multiple words as in your sample):

```
awk -F"[ ,]" '{gsub("\"","");$1=$1}1' OFS=, file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[," ]' '{OFS=","; print $1,$2,$4,$7}' file
```

Output:

```
2600,Sale,Approved,244.72
2601,Sale,Approved,490.51
2602,Sale,Approved,52.82
2603,Sale,Approved,88.10
```

I suppose there is no other whitespace.